# Skipping fragments in an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with 3 fragments. The first fragment is not added to the backstack. So my navigation is:

A -> B -> C, or
A -> C

I implemented `onNavigateUp` to remove the fragments from the backstack and it works.

I also have a button on the actionbar, which clears info in the fragments and switches to the first fragment.

If I'm in the third fragment and then click the button to go to the first, is replacing the fragment enough to remove the second and third fragments from the backstack or should I call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` too?

**EDIT**

I added this code to move back to the first fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
switchFragment(fragmentA, false);

fragmentA.clear();
```

And all switchFragment does is:

```
protected void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container_fragments, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

    if (addToBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

    currentFragment = fragment;
}
```

However, even though `fragmentA.clear()` is called, the textviews are not cleared.

Is it because the fragment's has still created?

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly to said that when you call replace by `FragmentTransaction` by default `AndroidOS` will just

> remove an existing fragment. If it was added to a container, its view
>   is also removed from that container.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))

and will not `push` or `pop` anything to/from `BackStack`. So if you are

> in the third fragment and then click the button to go to the first

if in the before you had called `addToBackStack()` then you should call `popBackStack()` too and if you were not call `addToBackStack()` in before you could not have to call `popBackStack()` to clear `BackStack`